# Matlab calling shell command

Tags: matlab, sh

I made a sh file and I called it in MATLAB like:

```
s=system('autorun.sh')
```

When I try:

```
./autorun.sh
```

on Linux, it works. But, when I tried:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm < autorun.m
```

it didn't work (although the screen displayed s=0 which means success)

Comment: Did you try `s=system('./autorun.sh')`?

Comment: so how do you know it didn't work?

Comment: Thanks Chris. The problem is solved.